# No se me crea la base de datos Symfony Many to many

Tags: mysql, doctrine

Tengo dos clases la clase Usuario y la clase Funcionalidad que las relaciono con manytomany en symfony pero cuando ejecuto doctrine:schema:update --force
no me genera la base de dato de la relacion aqui mi codigo

Entidad Usuario:

namespace SIPACBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * Usuario
 */
class Usuario implements UserInterface
{
    // ...

```
/**
 * Many Usuarios have Many Funcionalidades.
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Funcionalidad", inversedBy="usuarios")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="usuarios_funcionalidades")
 */
private $funcionalidades;

public function __construct() {
    $this->funcionalidades = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}

// ...
/**
 * @var int
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $username;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $password;

/**
 * @var bool
 */
private $email;


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set username
 *
 * @param string $username
 * @return Usuario
 */
public function setUsername($username)
{
    $this->username = $username;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get username
 *
 * @return string 
 */

/**
 * Set password
 *
 * @param string $password
 * @return Usuario
 */
public function setPassword($password)
{
    $this->password = $password;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get password
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getPassword()
{
    return $this->password;
}

/**
 * Set email
 *
 * @param boolean $email
 * @return Usuario
 */
public function setEmail($email)
{
    $this->email = $email;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get email
 *
 * @return boolean 
 */
public function getEmail()
{
    return $this->email;
}


//Implementacion de la interfaz de roles
public function equals(UserInterface $users){
    return $this->getEmail()==$users->getUsername();
}

public function eraseCredentials() {
    return false;
}

public function getRoles() {
   //return array("ROLE_USUARIO");

     return array(
        'ROLE_USER',
        // ...
        new UserDependentRole($this) // ROLE dinámico
    );
}

public function getUsername() {
    return $this->getEmail();
}

public function getSalt() {
    return false;
```

}

```
}
```

Entidad Funcionalidad:

namespace SIPACBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
/**
 * Funcionalidad
 */
class Funcionalidad
{
  // ...
    /**
     * Many Funcionalidades have Many Usuarios.
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Usuario", mappedBy="funcionalidades")
     */

```
private $usuarios;

public function __construct() {
    $this->usarios = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}


/**
 * @var int
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $nombre;


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set nombre
 *
 * @param string $nombre
 * @return Funcionalidad
 */
public function setNombre($nombre)
{
    $this->nombre = $nombre;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get nombre
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getNombre()
{
    return $this->nombre;
}
```

}
 espero me ayuden

Answer (score 1):

En tu codigo no aparece la anotacion **entity()**. Deberias tener algo como esto:

```
namespace SIPACBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM; 
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface; 
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

    /**
     * Usuario
     *
     * @ORM\Table(name="usuario")
     * @ORM\Entity()
     */

     class Usuario implements UserInterface { // ...
```

Si no indicas el @ORM\Entity() symfony no puede saber que eso es una entidad y por tanto no te crea la tabla el orm.